# How to get the nodes with duplicate property value in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a particular node of type Person and that particular node has some properties say name,age,dob etc. Now, there are some nodes with same name i.e there are multiple nodes with name  'JOHN' , some for 'DAVID' etc.

I want to count the nodes with same name.

ex. result should  be:
JOHN  - 2
DAVID  -5

something like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think you accidentally created duplicate nodes, now you want to find those nodes whose count is more then 1

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WITH p.name as name,COUNT(p) as count 
WHERE count>1
RETURN name,count
```